# Free tool to Create/Edit PNG Images?

Tags: image, png

Is there any free tool available for creating and editing PNG Images?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net/) will create and edit PNGs with gusto. It's an excellent program in many respects. It's free as in beer and speech.

Comment: I like it in general, but there are some gigantic holes in it, such as a lack of a magic eraser (!!!).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "magic eraser," but try using the recolor tool and recoloring to transparent.

Comment: Your link is wrong, you want http://www.getpaint.net/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the term (at least) "Magic Eraser" is an Adobe trademark.  Whether or not they've patented the concept (and are willing to fight for it) is another matter.

Comment: !!!! Be very careful with this link, it will coerce you to install other products !!!!!

Comment: @JimRhodes Here's a direct link to the download page: http://www.dotpdn.com/downloads/pdn.html

Comment: The installer is now bloated with crap utilities

Answer (score 44):

[The GIMP](http://gimp.org/) (GNU Image Manipulation Program).
It's free, open source and runs on Windows and Linux (and maybe Mac?).

Answer (score 31):

I use [Pixlr](http://pixlr.com/editor/) - an online photo editor, it has great filters and user friendly interface.

Answer (score 5):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is a vector drawing program that exports PNG images.  So, you end up editing SVG documents and exporting them to PNGs.  Inkscape is good if you're starting from scratch, but wouldn't be ideal if you just want to edit existing PNGs.

Note--Inkscape is open source and available for free on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [GD](http://www.libgd.org/) can handle PNGs too; heck, you could even do stuff with nothing but [gdk-pixbuf](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk-pixbuf/stable/).  Are you looking for a graphical editor, or scriptable/embeddable libraries?